# How to test a setter function in controller which passes a value to service setter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have my HTML, which contains a modal window in which is an `ng-repeat`

```
<strong>Data Type:</strong><select ng-options="dataTypes for dataTypes in dataTypeItems"
                                               ng-model="dataTypes"
                                               ng-change="setDataType(dataTypes)">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
            </select>
```

My HTML communicates with my `mainCtrl`, specifically the `setDataType(dataType)` method :

```
$scope.setDataType = function (dataT) {
    getDataService.setDataType(dataT);
};
```

Which in turn fires the String value `dataType` over to a setter in my Service (`getDataService`):

```
setDataType: function (dataT) {

        dataType = dataT;

    },
```

I'm just totally confused as to how to test this.  How do I test the function in my controller which simply calls a function in my service?  How do I test this without checking my service to see if the value has changed?  *DO* I test getters and setters?

Comment: Are you familiar with `console.log()`? it's a useful way of outputting data when you are testing.

Comment: Yeah I am, not sure how this ties into my question though?

Comment: Really what I'm trying to decipher is - Should I be testing just the setter in my service, should I be testing it at all, or should I be testing my function in my controller.  If the last option - how on earth do I test this independent of my service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you would do the two tests separately. The test in your controller should just test that it's calling the correct method:

```
it('.setDataType should call getDataService.setDataType with the correct parameter', inject(function (getDataService) {
    spyOn(getDataService, 'setDataType');

    $scope.setDataType('myDataType');

    expect(getDataService.setDataType).toHaveBeenCalledWith('myDataType');
}));
```

Comment: Thank you, although it may seem silly to you this has clarified an awful lot for me.

Comment: No worries, glad to help! (pssss, don't forget an upvote :)